# Sharing a public render parameter value across pages

Tags: portlet

I am using a `Public Render Parameter` in `WebSphere Portal`.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev-portlet/pltcom_pubrndrprm.dita

Using the `Web Content Viewer portlet`.
I've created 2 separate pages on `Portal`, each one containing a `Web Content Viewer portlet`.

Each page reads the value of `CUSTOM_CONTEXT` and displays it if a value has been set.
If a value has not been set yet, it displays a textfield and submit button, allowing user to provide a string.

When I set the value of `CUSTOM_CONTEXT` to the string `TEST` on page 1, the page reloads and `TEST` is displayed back to me.
However, when I navigate to page 2, I still see the textfield?
As though the value has not been set for that page.
How can I have the value shared across all pages?

If I navigate back to page 1, the value is still store as `TEST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev-portlet/pltcom_pubrndrprm.dita

"For some use cases, it can be required to limit parameter sharing. For example, this case can occur if you have two pairs of navigator or viewer portlets on two different pages, where each pair must be coordinated. However, the pairs must not interfere across pages so that the navigator on the first page does not influence the viewer on the second page. For such cases, the portal makes it possible to limit the sharing scope for public render parameters on a page basis. *The parameter sharing scope for a page is controlled by a page parameter param.sharing.scope. You can set it from the Page Properties view under Advanced options > I want to set parameters. If you set a value for this parameter, portlets on the page share their public render parameters only with other portlets on the same page or on pages with the same scope.*"